# How to know if a web page is valid and not a man in the middle fake page?

Tags: man-in-the-middle, account-security, facebook

Recently, the facebook page changed on my computer (on others from the same router, I get the regular page). I checked the ssl certificate, and it seems to be authentic, however, as the page does not look professionally designed, I am worried it is a man in the middle attack. How to be sure if it is legitimate or not ?

[image: facebook login]

Certificate information : 
[image]

Comment: are you sure you type the right url?

Comment: While you post the issuer of the certificates, here there is a link where you can read other information: https://www.thesslstore.com/blog/5-ways-to-determine-if-a-website-is-fake-fraudulent-or-a-scam/

Comment: The url is correct, for the issuer see edit

Comment: Why do you think it looks incorrect? What were you expecting?

Comment: @schroeder, you can visit facebook and see for yourself. 1. This is not the normal facebook look. 2. No report of the new look on the internet. 3. no one of my facebook friends has this look. 4. When I check on other computers (same router), I get another look, which is the regular one. 5. sub-pages have the regular look, only the home page has this different look

Comment: Maybe Facebook serving a different page to you, based on something that you did earlier, using cookies or some other mechanism to link you to a previous session.  Is it possible for you to delete your cookies and browser history and try again?  If not, do you have a different browser on the same device that you can use to test?

Comment: Unfortunately no, the regular look has appeared again and I can no longer repeat or access the modified look. Either the hacker (if there is effectively one) has noticed my activity or something else. I didn't delete any cookie or session infos, didn't install or updated anything (I am on ubuntu 16.04 if that's important), the regular look just appeared again by itself...To be clear, the modified look was persistent to the reboot of the OS.

Comment: The certificate information presented above is valid for facebook.  (Information as well as Serial #, SHA-1, and SHA-256 match.)   This means the HTTP request to `https://www.facebook.com` was likely not tampered with (unless a hacker has obtained facebook's private key or broken some aspect of the underlying encryption which is quite unlikely).  This doesn't mean it was safe; e.g., some attacker may have gotten access to facebook CDN.  Or it could be safe and something like a temporary misconfiguration or A/B test at facebook.

Comment: @drjimbob, yes it could be a test, because the blue color of the page, is the same as the facebook new logo

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have installed any certificates in your operating system or browser trust store, you can be fairly confident that any page using HTTPS is not the result of a MITM attack. In your particular case, it sounds more like a CSS resource failed to load, resulting in the corrupted layout you briefly observed.

An attacker who is sophisticated enough to perform a MITM attack against a TLS connection without getting you to trust their certificate manually is likely going to also be sophisticated enough to correctly copy a web page design so that it is completely indistinguishable from the original, legitimate layout.

You should verify that:

1. You have not installed any certificates that you don't trust.
2. The domain you are visiting to really is the domain you want to visit.
3. Your browser and operating system are up-to-date.

Comment: Well, it depends on the attacker motivation. Sophisticated or not, if its motivation is to inform me that he can attack me or that to know that indeed I am the owner of the pc he targeted. I also was thinking it was a CSS loading problem, however, the the different look remained even after an F5 reload, and after rebooting the os, the browser and router. Anyway, now the page is back to its regular look again, hope it was just a glitch in the matrix :)

Comment: @user3147619 No one is going to inform you that they can attack you, _especially_ not by changing the layout of a web page. If it remained even after reload, then it could have been a caching issue.